# Retrofit 1.9: How would I post data to this endpoint?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, retrofit

Hi i have an endpoint as follows:

> /api/v1/registration?

I have to post the following params to this endpoint which accepts it in this way.

> user[email]=john@google.com&user[password]=030386

so overall it would look like this

> /api/v1/registration?user[email]=john@google.com&user[password]=030386

I believe the API is a rails environment but I am really confused with these params. Are they arrays? I am not sure.

I have this so far

```
@POST(URLConstants.CREATE_ACCOUNT)
    void createUser(@Body CreateUser createUser, Callback<Response> callback);
```

Ignore the response call back, I am only interested to in the raw response for now.

And this is my POJO CreateUser

```
public class CreateUser {

    @SerializedName("user")
    private ArrayList<AccountFields> mAccountFields;

    public CreateUser(ArrayList<AccountFields> accountFields) {
        this.mAccountFields = accountFields;
    }

    public static class AccountFields{
        @SerializedName("email")
        private String mEmail;

        @SerializedName("password")
        private String mPassword;

        public AccountFields(String mEmail, String mPassword) {
            this.mEmail = mEmail;
            this.mPassword = mPassword;
        }
    }

}
```

The server returns a 500, internal server error. I think the problem is on my side since I can test the call on postman which works fine.

How do I send this data?

**EDIT 1: What about these params**

> user[answers_attributes][0][answer]=bar
>
> user[answers_attributes][0][question_id]=1
>
> user[answers_attributes][1][answer]=foo
>
> user[answers_attributes][1][question_id]=2

Comment: That is a hash, equivalent would be: {user: {email: john@google.com, password: 030386} }. You'll need to nest the email and password as a value to user. Can you see/paste the actual post and it's body?

Comment: @omarvelous thanks, it worked

Comment: @omarvelous can you check my edit, I have also come across these params before, what is the equivalent in JSON =?

Comment: The answers_attributes part is an array:

`{user: {answer_attributes: [{answer: bar, question_id: 1},  {answer: foo, question_id: 2}]}}`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks omarvelous

This is the POJO that serialised the data

```
public class CreateUser {

    @SerializedName("user")
    private AccountFields mAccountFields;

   public CreateUser(AccountFields accountFields) {
      this.mAccountFields = accountFields;
   }
   public static class AccountFields{
        @SerializedName("email")
        private String mEmail;

        @SerializedName("password")
        private String mPassword;

        public AccountFields(String mEmail, String mPassword) {
            this.mEmail = mEmail;
            this.mPassword = mPassword;
        }
}
```